# How to round up the answer (numbers) of this calculation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The answer sometimes comes in decimals, how to round up the answer?

E.g. From this answer **30354.16667** to this **30354**

```
<script>
 
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

function doStuff() {
  const rate = 0.155;
  const vprice = document.getElementById("price").value;
  const downPayment = document.getElementById("DownPay").value;
  const period = document.getElementById("app").value;
  const res = (vprice - downPayment) * rate / period;
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res;
  google.script.run.userClicked({
    vprice,
    downPayment,
    rate,
    period,
    res
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Math.round()`:

```
const resRounded = Math.round(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to round to the closest number, use:

```
const resRound = Math.round(res)
```

If you want to floor it(round down) use:

```
const resRound = Math.floor(res)
```

If you want to ceil it (round up) use:

```
const resRound = Math.ceil(res)
```